# Sign a gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, sign

I have met an issue of "signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package"  when releasing a gradle plugin using a signed jar, for testing it, I created a [gradle-hello-plugin](https://github.com/andxu/gradle-hello-plugin), and signed the jar: (https://github.com/andxu/gradle-hello-plugin/blob/master/signed-gradle-hello-plugin-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar), I met the following error when I run 'gradle hello', does someone know how to release a gradle plugin signed? Thanks.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'test-project'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.example.greeting']
   > Could not create task ':hello'.
      > Could not create task of type 'Greeting'.
         > Could not generate a decorated class for class org.example.greeting.Greeting.
            > class "org.example.greeting.Greeting_Decorated"'s **signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package**
```

Answer (score 0):

Find an existing bug: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/6860, start from gradle 4.8, the signed plugins are not supported, I tried to use my hello plugin, it works on gradle 4.7